# The limit containing integer part

Tags: limits

I have the following problem. Does this limit exist:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}|x|\cdot(-1)^{\lfloor1/x\rfloor}$$

where $\lfloor\cdot\rfloor$ is a integer part function (greatest integer not greater than given number).

Does the squeeze theorem hold in this case? Could I say that since $$-|x|\le|x|\cdot(-1)^{\lfloor1/x\rfloor}\le|x|$$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}|x|=0$ the limit under consideration exists and equals to 0?

Comment: Yes the squeeze theorem applies and it is the correct approach,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the squeeze theorem applies and you have used it correctly to show that
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}|x|\cdot(-1)^{\lfloor1/x\rfloor} = 0
$$.

Comment: Thank you. It's quite tricky to use this theorem to handle with sophisticated limits.

Comment: It looks like you can handle the trickiness.  The difficult part in this question is to recognize that the squeeze theorem applies with $-|x|$ and $|x|$.